# laravel middleware always returns to login page, even if authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-middleware

This problem appeared after I added the middleware on the route, I used the default auth middleware.
I'm here to manually create a controller according to the laravel documentation, I checked the process inside the controller and the status is successfully logged in with the 'dd' syntax, but every time I add the 'auth' middleware to the middleware it always returns me to the login page, here in the user table i changed 'id' to 'nim'.

[this is my users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5s66.png)

[this is my authenticate procces in my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZRLG.png)

[this is my route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqSRX.png)

[and this is my default auth middleware named authenticated.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaZEL.png)

I'm very grateful if anyone helps me find a solution, thanks dev!

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

This condition in your middleware is causing the problem:

```
if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
   return route('login');
}
```

If in the header of your request you don't send `'Accept': 'application/json'` you will be redirected to your login page.

Just correct your condition, or simply remove this condition, and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks sir, i do analysis and can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should change your condition in your middleware with the below code if you don't want to send the `application/json` request.

```
if ($request->expectsJson()) {
     return route('login');
   }
```

If you don't have `'Accept': 'application/json'` header in your request then add `'Accept': 'application/json'` header in the request and let the middleware code as it is.

Comment: thanks sir, i do analysis and can solve my problem